# Is there a way to get the current page no. inside a body in Reporting Services 2005?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I need to calculate the current page no. in Reporting Services 2005 inside a body to determine if the page is the first page in duplex print. 
I know we can retrieve this number in the header, but is there a possibility to calculate this inside the body itself?

Cheers,
Steffen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is probably a duplicate from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11322001/419956).

Unfortunately the answer seems to be that you [can't access the page number in the body](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/425893/global-page-number-value-to-be-accessed-from-body-section-in-ssrs-2008) of a report, so what you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't access the global page number in the body. Maybe this thread in the SQL Server forum can help solving the issue: [SSRS-Pagination on report body](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ab9c18bc-ee37-45a2-a52d-628c12d08b33/)